# comparing different subversion respositories

Tags: svn

subversion 1.4.2

We have a repository. We are going to back up that repository to our server. However, our customer wants to know that if we were to restore that repository, how do they know if someone has tried to change something or do something bad to that repository.

We will keep the repository on our development server. And backup that repository to our backup server.

How can we confirm that both repositories are exactly the same?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: Given repositories that users have access to, how can you do this except for a specific point in time that's gone the moment your analysis is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to use `svnadmin dump` for backuping. Then you can calculate MD5 or other hash sum on the dump files and compare them.

Comment: This is the easiest idea that comes to my mind, too, but could have practical problems due to the repository ID (that will differ - not sure whether that'll be in the dump). In the end, you may have to do a `diff` instead of a `md5` and verify that only the repo ID and path have changed and nothing else. Still, the best way to go +1